# Proving $(A\setminus B)\setminus (C\setminus B)=A\setminus (B\cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wish to verify that:
$$
(A\setminus B)\setminus (C\setminus B)=A\setminus (B\cup C)
$$
I wish to present my attempt: (For the $(\subseteq)$ implication)
\begin{align*}
&x\in(A\setminus B)\setminus (C\setminus  B) \\
\implies&x\in(A\setminus B)\wedge x\notin(C\setminus B) \\
\implies&[(x\in A)\wedge(x\notin B)]\wedge[(x\notin C)\wedge(x\in B)]
\end{align*}
Unfortunately, I am stuck at this process and I am unable to proceed. I am new to elements of set theory and I am currently practicing such practice problems.

Comment: Note that $x \notin C \setminus B$ means that $x \notin C$ *or* $x \in B$.

Comment: To my surprise I wasn't aware of that. Can you show me how the forward implication is done? I would then be able to do reverse implication on my own.

Comment: @azif00's observation is that $x\in C\setminus B\iff x\in C\land x\notin B$, so taking negations $x\notin C\setminus B\iff x\notin C\lor x\in B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make implications two sided:$$\begin{align}x\in(A\setminus B)\setminus(C\setminus B)&\iff x\in A\setminus B\land x\notin C\setminus B\\&\iff x\in A\land x\notin B\land x\notin C\\&\iff x\in A\land x\notin B\cup C\\&\iff x\in A\setminus(B\cup C).\end{align}$$Alernatively, you could prove the tautology $((a\land\neg b)\land\neg(c\land\neg b))\iff a\land\neg(b\lor c)$ with a truth table.

Answer (score 1):

I like to approach such type of problem through the definitions and properties involved.

Precisely, one has that

\begin{align*}
(A - B) - (C - B) & = (A\cap B^{c})\cap(C\cap B^{c})^{c}\\\\
& = (A\cap B^{c})\cap(C^{c}\cup B)\\\\
& = (A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c})\cup(A\cap B^{c}\cap B)\\\\
& = (A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c})\cup\varnothing\\\\
& = A\cap(B^{c}\cap C^{c})\\\\
& = A\cap(B\cup C)^{c}\\\\
& = A - (B\cup C)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Minor problem with your work so far: suppose $x \not \in C \setminus B$.

If $x \in C \setminus B$, then $x \in C$ and $x \not \in B$.

The negation of this statement, to yield $x \not \in C \setminus B$, is $x \not \in C$ **or** $x \in B$. More generally:

$$\neg (P \land Q) = (\neg P) \lor (\neg Q)$$

So what you have, then, is that

$$x\in(A\setminus B)\setminus (C\setminus B) \implies [(x\in A)\land (x\notin B)]\land [(x\notin C)\lor (x\in B)]$$

There are two possibilities for the second statement. Take $x \in B$, though, and you'll have that $x \not \in B$ contradicts this. Thus, only the choice for $x \not \in C$ is valid:

$$x\in(A\setminus B)\setminus (C\setminus B) \implies (x\in A)\land (x\notin B)\land(x\notin C)$$

From the definition of $A \setminus (B \cup C)$, you should be able to use this to reach your desired conclusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I like indeed understand your approach this is how I wish to approach other similar problems. Thank you :)